# Limit with parameters

Tags: limits

Prove that for all $$t\in \Bbb R^{+} , n\in \Bbb N $$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{(e^{n}+t)^{ln(x)}}{x^n}=\infty $$
My attempt was to do ln() to the numerator and denominator or lupital without any succeed.

Comment: I don't think so it diverges for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(e^{n}+t)^{\ln{x}}}{x^n}=e^{\log{(e^n+t)^{\ln{x}}}-\ln{(x^n)}}=e^{{\ln{(x)}}\log{(e^n+t)}-n\ln{(x)}}=\left(\frac{e^{\ln{(e^n+t)}}}{e^n}\right)^{\ln{x}}$$
Now since $e^n>\ln{(n)}$ then $\ln{(e^n+t)}>e^
{n}$ since $t>0$. So $e^{\ln{(e^n+t)}}>e^{n}$ and then
$$\left(\frac{e^{\ln{(e^n+t)}}}{e^n}\right)^{\ln{x}}=a^{\ln{x}}$$
where $a>1$.
Finally $$\lim_{x\to 0}a^{\ln{x}}=0$$

It is not true that the limit is $\infty$ $\forall n, t>0$.